# Is it possible to achieve a negative score?

Tags: azul

I was playing Azul the other day, and by a bad choice, one of the players ended up subtracting points until they were in negative numbers.

How should you act in these cases? Is the negative score maintained or does it remain at 0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot go below 0 points, so you will get a break on the penalty you have to take.

From the [rules](https://www.planbgames.com/en/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=9), under scoring:

> Finally, at the end of the Wall-tiling phase, check if you have any
>   tiles in your floor line. For each tile in your floor line, you lose
>   the number of points indicated directly above it. Adjust your
>   scoring marker on your score track accordingly (**however, you
>   can never drop below 0 points**).